# Android GDX Box2D Triangle Shape

Tags: android, box2d, libgdx

I need a triangle shape definition for Box2D GDX Android.
Would I just divide the width by 3 or is there a class for it?
Here is code for normal rectangle:

```
            _rect1 = CCSprite.sprite("RectWood.png");
            _rect1.setPosition(CGPoint.make(-10, -10));
            this.addChild(_rect1);
            //Create box
            BodyDef Box1BodyDef = new BodyDef();
            Box1BodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
            Box1BodyDef.position.set(350/PTM_RATIO, 80/PTM_RATIO);

            // The body is also added to the world.
            Body Box1Body = _world.createBody(Box1BodyDef);
            Box1Body.setUserData(_rect1);

            // Define the shape.
            PolygonShape Box1Box = new PolygonShape();


            Box1Box.setAsBox(10/PTM_RATIO, 50/PTM_RATIO);
            Box1Body.createFixture(Box1Box,1.5f);
```

:) Thanks, Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add 3 vertices to your `Box1Box` object instead of calling `setAsBox()`.

Comment: sorry, i am really (like a real newbie) a newbie at this stuff. Would anyone know how to add 3 verticies? :)

Comment: ok... thanks! I will just figure out how to port to libgdx.
:) thankyouthankyou!